# mkdir -p awk input

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, mkdir

I want to create an input argument for mkdir -p, I have one directory tree structure in one server and I want to copy this same structure to another machine using a mkdir -p command. The two machines don't "talk" to each other, no telnet, no ssh. The objective is to insert a simple command (mkdir -p master/{one/{a,b,c},two/{a,b,c},three/{a,b,c}}) in a install script in server2, I don't want an extra file and I can't access server1 from server2.

Something like master/{one/{a,b,c},two/{a,b,c},three/{a,b,c}}. I'm using  ( find . -type d ) to find the directories and now I need the awk part.

What is the best way to create an awk command to find the tree like structure ?

```
Directory tree:

-- master
----one 
--------a
--------b
--------c
----two
--------a
--------b
--------c
----three
--------a
--------b
--------c    

Mkdir command:

mkdir -p master/{one/{a,b,c},two/{a,b,c},three/{a,b,c}}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify. Do you already have a structure in place and you want to find the arguments for mkdir -p that would reproduce the existing structure?

Comment: Yes Steve Weet. The issue is copying the same structure from a existing server to a new server.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you really need to generate the pattern you are showing, or would the expanded version do? (because getting the expanded version is trivial; it's just the output of find and shell will be expanding the thing you wrote before mkdir ever sees it)

Comment: The objective is to put the mkdir -p with a pattern in a shell script.

Comment: I can't see how awk is supposed to fit into this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to cp an existing dir structure, you could consider to use tar and untar. tar can work with your `find` too.

well some example, just show what I meant.

on your existing serverA:

```
find .... -print |xargs tar -cf - |ssh user@SERVER_B "cd someDir; tar -xf - "
```

**updated**

if you prefer copy a file to serverB and fire it, here is another dirty solution:

on serverA:

```
kent$  mkdir a/b/{1..5}/c  

now we have a tree, then :
kent$  find -type d|sed -r '/^.$/{s:.:#!/bin/bash:};{s/^\./mkdir -p &/}' 
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ./a
mkdir -p ./a/b
mkdir -p ./a/b/4
mkdir -p ./a/b/4/c
mkdir -p ./a/b/3
mkdir -p ./a/b/3/c
mkdir -p ./a/b/1
mkdir -p ./a/b/1/c
mkdir -p ./a/b/5
mkdir -p ./a/b/5/c
mkdir -p ./a/b/2
mkdir -p ./a/b/2/c
```

now you can save the output to a script file, on B go to the target DIr, then run it on B

Comment: Kent, there are many ways to do it I think. What I want to do is put a command in a script and generate a directory tree corresponding to another server directory tree. I don't want to have a extra tar file. I want to do it in a command line.

Comment: Don't have ssh between each other.

Comment: On server-A : "find -type d > dir-list" then send the file to the server-B and run : "mkdir -p $(<dir-list)"

Comment: well, you can send the dir-list text file, but why not a tar?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your needs : copy the directorys tree from server-A to server-B, so

On server-A :

```
cd /path/to/dir
find -type d | ssh server-B 'xargs -I% mkdir -p "/path/to/dir/%"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This find/sort/GNU sed oneliner makes a start:

```
mkdir -p master/{one,two,three}/{a,b,c}
find master -type d | sort |
sed -r 'H;${x;s/\n//;y/\n/ /;:a;s/([^ ]*) (\1\/[^ ]* )/\2/;ta;:b;s#(([^ /]*/)+)([^ /]+) \1([^ /]+)#\1\3,\4#;tb;s#(([^ /]*/)*)([^ ]*)#\1{\3}#g;:c;s#(([^ /]*/)*)([^/ ]+)/(\{[^}]*\}) \1([^ /]+)/\4#\1\3,\5/\4#;tc;s#/([^/ ]*)/\{#/{\1}/{#g;s/^/mkdir -p /p};d'
mkdir -p master/{one,three,two}/{a,b,c}
```

It's a bit longwinded to explain but in essence it makes the sorted directory listing into a string. Then uses loops and matching to condense it back to the expression. Finally it prepends the `mkdir -p` command.
It doesn't produce the most efficient expression, but this might be improved if a different sort was used.